# DB Connection ERROR after publishing the web application in IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

After publishing web application in IIS 6 I am getting follwoing error

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

It runs fine in development server with same DB connection

Please help me

Comment: This may help u : 
http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331

Answer (score 0):

there can be multiple issues with this. But basic problem is that web server is not able to locate DB server.

Try below steps to figure out the exact issue

1. is the DB server pingable from your web server?
2. are you providing correct user while connecting to SQL server.
3. are you able to connect to the DB server from web server using the username you provided in your config file?

try all above and let me know your result.

Comment: then try the link posted by Bui Akinori above. It contains more scenarios.